# SAS Array Looping: Checking if Array[x] is NULL and then filling it in

Tags: arrays, sas

So, dealing with SAS Dx Arrays: I've got an array, disease_category. What I'm doing currently is assigning each array[x] an individual category, then rolling everything up to a final array.

What I would like to do is check if array[x] is NULL - if it is, then I'd like to fill it in with the disease_category label. Otherwise, I would like to move onto the next array (array{x+1]) and repeat the process, up until the array is full and/or the looping is complete. I've been working on this for a while. I suspect that a DO loop is necessary, and a counting mechanism.

```
 array disease_category[*] _character_ disease1-disease10;

 If DGNSCD1 in: ('033','390','391','037','045')
 then disease_category[1] = "Immunization";

 if (DGNSCD1 =: "3200" AND %AGE(1,5))
 then disease_category[2] = "Hemophilius";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the following, plus either a second array of disease category names, or a format that converts the category number to a label.  I like the latter.

```
proc format;
value discat
1="Immunization"
2="Hemophilius"
other="NONE"
;
quit;
```

Then in your data step:

```
do _n = 1 to dim(disease_category);
 if missing(disease_category[_n]) then disease_category[_n]=put(_n,discat.);
end;
```